# Из string в массив vector

Tags: c++

Подскажите как "перегнать" строку **std::string** в вектор **std::vector<int>**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, вот вам несколько из тысячи возможных способов:

```
std::vector<int> v(s.length());
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < s.length(); idx++)
    v[idx] = s[idx];
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/nWUwHX

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (char c : s)
    v.push_back(c);
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/4FMrPk

```
std::vector<int> v(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/1dJ9a2

Comment: Последний вариант самый лучший

Comment: @mikillskegg: ага, подбирал по нарастанию идиоматичности.